# Word for one who does not eat onions

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for someone who does not eat onions? I remember having heard this word somewhere but do not remember it now.

Comment: As someone who is allergic to onions, it would be nice if such a word was in common use.

Comment: I propose a new word "unonioner".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone who is *[alliumphobic](http://www.phobiasource.com/alliumphobia-2/)* has a fear of onions ([*allium cepa*](http://www.botany.com/allium.html)) in general, and certainly wouldn't eat them!

An [alliaphage](http://wordinfo.info/unit/2736) is someone who eats garlic (and, by extension, onions), so if you can negate that in some graceful way (*analliaphage*?), you'll have a word for someone who doesn't eat onions.

Edit: Per the comments below, I suggest the term *non-alliaphage* for someone who doesn't eat onions.

Comment: To be pedantic, I wouldn't recommend anyone to expect what you mean by a Latin-Greek behemoth of a neologism.

Comment: @DavidRivers True. There isn't a single word for every concept in the English language, that's why we have sentences. So if we really must crowbar in a single word, it seems we'll have to live with some kind of Latin-Greek behemoth of a neologism. Is there a single word for "*Latin-Greek behemoth of a neologism*"? :)

Comment: @Hugo  Although not a single word, *[inkhorn term](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/inkhorn.htm)*, "words which were being used by scholarly writers but which were unknown or uncommon in ordinary speech" may be relevant.

Comment: @DavidRivers: Yes, as I was drifting off to sleep last night, _non-alliaphage_ popped into my head as a less hideous chimera.

Answer (score 2):

Background: The terms "akreophagy" (var. "acreophagy") and "aristophagy" were coined in the 19th century to mean anti-flesh-eating.

http://www.archive.org/stream/cu31924091890685#page/n25/mode/2up
http://www.caninestyle.co.uk/ordergoldenage/Home/page8.html

Allium is the onion genus; the term "alliaphagy" is attested as a term for a garlic- or bulb-eater:

http://books.google.com/books?q=alliaphagy

In the same way, you can coin a term for an anti-bulb-eating: "analliaphagy". However this suffers from overgeneralization: it can mean an avoidance of any plant in the allium genus. If you do not mind mixing your Greek and Latin roots (which offends the purists but is still commonplace), then use the Latin word "cepa", "onion": "acepaphagy" or "ancepaphagy".

The corresponding terms for a person who does not eat onions, then, are **acepaphage** or **ancepaphage**.

Answer (score -2):

*Alliumphobia* is the word that you are looking for, but I think alliumphobia describes the phobia in the scent of certain plants including onions.

Answer (score -2):

@eeerahul, I'd say that 99.99 percent of people in western countries  are subjected to onion and garlic cooked foods from birth, so there is no exact single word in English for non-onion garlic eaters

As in Hindi and Sanskrit we have word like *[jain food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jain_vegetarianism)*, *[satvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sattvic_diet)*, *bhojan* etc... because these types of food habits are found only in Asian countries like India, Sri lanka, China, Bhutaan even in Pakistan etc.

Hence you have a great question, and you can raise this concern to authorities like Oxford University Press, Cambridge, Harvard press ... in order to have a single word for this type of eating food habit. Especially because "organic" food is spreading across the world rapidly; we need a single word to describe it in one shot :)

Answer (score -4):

*[Jain Vegetarians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jain_vegetarianism)* do not eat onion and garlic.

Comment: Yeah, but I was looking for a specific English word for this.

Comment: Or any root vegetable, and adhere to a whole bunch of other rules. Not eating onions does not define them. -1